# bash replace string in file with specific index

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I have 2 files:

`idfile.txt`:

```
1111
3333
```

`replace.xml`:

```xml
<condition="online" id="1111" >
<condition="online" id="2222" >
<condition="online" id="3333" >
<condition="online" id="4444" >
```

I need a script to get below `output.xml`:

```xml
<condition="offline" id="1111" >
<condition="online" id="2222" >
<condition="offline" id="3333" >
<condition="online" id="4444" >
```

I use:

```sh
while read line; do
grep $line replace.xml | sed 's/condition="online"/condition="offline"/g' replace.xml >> output.xml 
done < idfile.txt
```

My script replace all `condition="online"` in `condition="offline"`.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can't figure out what you want

Comment: `11111` is not equal to `1111` !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, `id` attribute value from `replace.xml` should match any of the entries from `idfile.txt` to fit the condition.

**Awk** + **paste** solution:

```
awk -v ids="$(paste -s -d'|' idfile.txt)" 'match($2,ids){ sub("online","offline",$1) }1' replace.xml
```

The output:

```
<condition="offline" id="1111" >
<condition="online" id="2222" >
<condition="offline" id="3333" >
<condition="offline" id="4444" >
```

Answer (score 0):

If your files are going to be large, I would use `awk`. Please note that your `idfile.txt` should be:

```
1111
3333
```

To get something interesting.

This is how I would do it with `awk`:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '
  BEGIN {
    while( (getline $l < "idfile.txt") > 0 ) {
      if( $l ~ /^.+$/ ) {
        id[$l] = 1;
      }
    }
    close("idfile.txt");
  }

  /^.+$/ {
    split($2, a, "\"");
    if( id[ a[2] ] ) {
      printf "<condition=\"online\" id=\"%s\">\n", a[2];
    }
    else {
      printf "<condition=\"offline\" id=\"%s\">\n", a[2];
    }
  }
' replace.xml >output.xml
```

The `BEGIN` block reads the id file to the `id` array. `awk` uses a hash to implement lookups so they are efficient. The regular expressions `/^.+$/` are meant to avoid processing empty lines. The code is meant to be contained in a `bash` (text) file.

`$2` will get the pieces `id="nnnn">` and the `split` will get in array `a[2]` the part of that within the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

**awk** one liner

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]; next} ($4 in a){gsub(/online/,"offline")}1' idfile.txt FS='"' replace.xml
```

`First` : Store all id's in `a`
`Next`, while iterating over replace.xml, if id i.e `$4` exists in array `a` then replace `online` with `offline`. Note: Field separator is `"` for replace.xml

Output

```
<condition="offline" id="1111" >
<condition="online" id="2222" >
<condition="offline" id="3333" >
<condition="online" id="4444" >
```